# Typescript : Typing arguments in a .map()

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to Typescript and trying to figure out the syntax.

I have an Autocomplete React Component, which takes in a `data` prop, which is an array of objects of shape `{ label:string, value:string }`. Relevant code from Autocomplete.tsx :

```
...

interface AutocompleteOption {
    label: string;
    value: string;
}

interface AutocompleteProps {
    className?: string;
    data: Array<object>;
    icon?: string;
    id?: string;
    onChange?: Function;
}

...

const Autocomplete = ({ id = "", className = "", data = [], icon = "", onChange }: AutocompleteProps): ReactElement => {
...
return (
    ...
    <div className={classnames("Autocomplete__values_list", isListVisible ? "active" : "")}>
        {data.map((option: AutocompleteOption) => {
            if (option.label.toLowerCase().includes(currentValue.toLowerCase())) {
                return (
                    <button
                        className="Autocomplete__option"
                        key={`option_${option.value}`}
                        onClick={(e) => {
                            handleSelectOption(e, option.label);
                        }}>
                        {option.label}
                    </button>
                );
            }
        })}
    </div>
    ...
)
}
```

The line with `{data.map((option: AutocompleteOption) => {` gets highlighted in my IDE with the following error :

```
Argument of type '(option: AutocompleteOption) => JSX.Element | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: object, index: number, array: object[]) => Element | undefined'.
  Types of parameters 'option' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'AutocompleteOption': label, value, keyts(2345)
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: `data: Array<object>;` Did you mean to do `data: Array<AutocompleteOption>`?

Comment: OMG that was it  -_-  Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

Please try to return something in the map, maybe that is the reason.

```
const Autocomplete = ({ id = "", className = "", data = [], icon = "", onChange }: AutocompleteProps): ReactElement => {
...
return (
    ...
    <div className={classnames("Autocomplete__values_list", isListVisible ? "active" : "")}>
        {data.map((option: AutocompleteOption) => {
            if (option.label.toLowerCase().includes(currentValue.toLowerCase())) {
                return (
                    <button
                        className="Autocomplete__option"
                        key={`option_${option.value}`}
                        onClick={(e) => {
                            handleSelectOption(e, option.label);
                        }}>
                        {option.label}
                    </button>
                );
            } else {
               return null;
            }
        })}
    </div>
    ...
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somebody found the solution in a comment :

> data: Array<object>; Did you mean to do data:
> Array<AutocompleteOption>?  –  Nicholas Tower

Thank you !